# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null (angular6)

Tags: angular6, ckeditor5

I am using Angular 6 + CkEditor5 and I am getting 'Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null'.

I am trying to build from source as mentioned here https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular/issues/26

In template:

`<div id="editor"></div>`

In typescript:

````
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor';
import Bold from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold';
import Italic from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/italic';

ClassicEditor.create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
  plugins: [ Bold, Italic ],
  toolbar: [ 'bold', 'italic']
} )
.then( editor => {
    console.log( 'Editor was initialized', editor );
} )
.catch( error => {
    console.error( error.stack );
} );```
````